# elasticSearch/npm: Elasticdump returns a "self signed certificate" error

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

I am able to get the json response for the elastic search query via an http client but on trying via elasticdump it gives an error stating - self signed certificate. What is a possible solution for this?

```
###> elasticdump --input "https://<server_ip>/elasticsearch/_cat/indi
ces?v" --output "c:\edmp.log" --type data
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:38:07 GMT | starting dump
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:38:08 GMT | Error Emitted => self signed certificate
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:38:08 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:38:08 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: self
 signed certificate
```

And same for queried searches:

```
###> elasticdump  --input "https://<server_ip>/elasticsearch/_search"
 --output "c:\edmp.log" --searchbody {"query": {"filtered":{"filter":{"bool":{"m
ust":[{"range":{"timestamp":{"gte":"now-5m"}}}]}},"query":{"query_string":{"anal
yze_wildcard":true,"query":"filter:value"}}}},"size":"100","sort":[{"timestamp":{
"order":"desc","unmapped_type":"boolean"}}]} --type data
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:31:14 GMT | starting dump
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:31:15 GMT | Error Emitted => self signed certificate
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:31:15 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Wed, 24 May 2017 03:31:15 GMT | dump ended with error (get phase) => Error: self
 signed certificate
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: ignore below, you can try this

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 elasticdump --input=.....
```

i think you can fork it and add `strictSSL` option to `false` for `request`.

More specific, this file https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/blob/master/lib/transports/elasticsearch.js

Comment: Thanks - this gives me more options now